# Get text between two words using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, string, titanium

I have a string, it looks like an XML file but actually it is just a normal string saved in a variable.

The **string** is like this:

```
<m:properties>
             <d:user_id m:type="Edm.Int64">37</d:user_id>
             <d:organization_id m:type="Edm.Int64">1</d:organization_id>
             <d:name>Test</d:name>
             <d:password>81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055</d:password>
             <d:email_id>test1@cs.com</d:email_id>
             <d:user_type_id m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:user_type_id>
             <d:is_valid m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:is_valid>
             <d:registration_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-10-25T11:20:08</d:registration_date>
           </m:properties>
```

I need to extract text within :

1. `<d:password> </d:password>`
2. `<d:email_id></d:email_id>`

The content of `<d:password> </d:password>` and `<d:email_id></d:email_id>` is dynamic.

How to use javascript String handling functions to extract the required texts?

Comment: You should **really** use an XML parser for this.

Comment: [Titanium has a built in robust, fast, and easy to use DOM parser](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML-method-parseString), why the heck are you using string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IF*** this string is regular (i.e. it's structure never changes), then you could use a regex but, it's awfully close to HTML/XML which are irregular and regex and irregular don't go together.  They don't go together so much that if I even suggest a regex, I'll lose all my rep in the downvote storm which would follow.  So...

***IF*** this string is regular, then this is a possible solution for quick and clean:

```
String name = text.split(">")[6].split("<")[0];
String password = text.split(">")[8].split("<")[0];
```

Here, the magic numbers 6 and 8 are the indices of the tags in your input string.  With a little further work, you could lose the magic numbers altogether but if the structure is fixed, constants might work OK for them.

Or, losing the magic numbers, and perhaps cleaner (although using magic numbers for the length of 'name>' and 'password>').

```
String name = text.substring(text.indexof("name>")+5).split("<")[0];
String password = text.substring(text.indexof("password>")+9).split("<")[0];
```

Both of these will work for any length of user name and password.

PS.  Of course, the first rule of programming is that there is no such thing as a structure that comes from outside your code which will never change ;)

PPS.  When I say 'any length', that is of course subject to the limits of Java and the Dalvik VM ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the string you posted is stored in a variable named myCode then here is what you need to extract the password and email out of myCode

```
var passwd = myCode.substring(myCode.indexOf("<d:password>")+12,myCode.length-myCode.indexOf("</d:password>"));
var email = myCode.substring(myCode.indexOf("<d:email_id>")+11,myCode.length-myCode.indexOf("</d:email_id>"));
```

Comment: The length of <d:password> and <d:email_id> may not be static. So calculation on the basis of that might not be a good idea!

Comment: I know, but at least it satisfies the requirement of this particular case, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, but this will not be a permanent solution, as it always changes. The string is actually a server response. So is their any way to answer the particular complexity?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer without too much care about counting things:

```
var password = text.split("<d:password>")[1].split("</d:password>")[0];
var email = text.split("<d:email_id>")[1].split("</d:email_id>")[0];
```

Here, the only thing you must make sure is that you don't have multiple identical tags. If many exist, the first index would say which occurrence you want. The other remains 0.